# TypeError: apickli.Apickli is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

Getting error :

> TypeError: apickli.Apickli is not a constructor

when I am trying to use Sendpostrequest.js again in my next step in a scenario.

From A.js i am trying to call Sendpostrequest for first step its working fine but when i am using it again i am getting error

> TypeError: apickli.Apickli is not a constructor.

Code: A.js

```
 Given(....
{
    Sendpostrequest(obj.domain, obj.requestheader, querystring.stringify(obj.requestbody)).then
    {
    } //works fine
});

When(....
{
    Sendpostrequest(obj.domain, obj.requestheader, querystring.stringify(obj.requestbody)).then
    {
    } //this one giving error
});
```

Sendpostrequest.js

```
'use strict';
const querystring = require('querystring');
let apickli = require('apickli');

const Sendpostrequest = (requesturl, header, body) => {
    apickli = new apickli.Apickli('https', requesturl);
    for (let key in header) {
        apickli.addRequestHeader(key, header[key]);
    }
    console.log("Header -------->", header);
    console.log("Url------------->", requesturl);
    if (body) {
        apickli.setRequestBody(body);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        apickli.post('', function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(response);
        });
    })
}
module.exports = Sendpostrequest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with class `apickli`, you have omitted `apickli` variable in first request, you may like to try something like following

```
'use strict';
const querystring = require('querystring');
const apickli = require('apickli');

const Sendpostrequest = (requesturl, header, body) => {
    this.apickli = new apickli.Apickli('https', requesturl);
    for (let key in header) {
        this.apickli.addRequestHeader(key, header[key]);
    }
    console.log("Header -------->", header);
    console.log("Url------------->", requesturl);
    if (body) {
        this.apickli.setRequestBody(body);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.apickli.post('', function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(response);
        });
    })
}
```

or use another variable name like `const apickliObj` instead of `this.apickli` that is you have to avoid omitting variable but if you still like to omit then include inside function like following

```
'use strict';
const querystring = require('querystring');

const Sendpostrequest = (requesturl, header, body) => {
    let apickli = require('apickli');
    apickli = new apickli.Apickli('https', requesturl);
    for (let key in header) {
        apickli.addRequestHeader(key, header[key]);
    }
    console.log("Header -------->", header);
    console.log("Url------------->", requesturl);
    if (body) {
        apickli.setRequestBody(body);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        apickli.post('', function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(response);
        });
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!